# How to keep adding half of a half until a given input

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to create the following sequence:

[image: sequence]

But I want to stop it when the added number becomes smaller than the input x.

Can anyone help explain how to use the while and for loops in this instance?

My attempt:

```
def series(x):
    y = 1
    while ? is greater than x:
         for i in range(?):
             y+=y/2
    return y

print(series(0.25))
```

Comment: The series begins *larger* than your argument of 0.25; adding positive values can *never* make it smaller.  Also, if you will trace your program as expected, you'll find that what you're adding is not the values you claim.
You need some debugging work before you're ready to post.  See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: @Prune He doesn't know what to put in place of `?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to track the current element of the series separately from the sum.  Watch what `y` does in your code and you'll see why it's wrong.  Your third step adds 1.5/2, not 0.5/2.

```
def series(x):
    sumx = 0
    y = 1
    while y >= x:
         sumx += y
         y /= 2
    return sumx

print(series(0.25))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def series(x):
    res = [1.0]
    while True:
        n = res[-1] / 2
        if n < x:
            return res
        res.append(n)
```

you can also make it a generator:

```
def series(x):
    n = 1.0
    while n > x:
        yield n
        n /= 2
```